Where in javascript:install:[bundler] are the tools installed to terminal?
Question regarding jsbundling-rails gem, asked on github and posting here also for more visibility.
I've tried intalling a couple different bundlers now for a new app, essentially getting the same error message in both cases. 'bun' or 'esbuild' is not recognized a valid command. Bun looks to be the simplest installation so we can use that example, where in the installation script is the bun command actually added? Does it attempt to add a symlink to path or is a task added directly to the rails app? Current theory is that my current terminal setup isn't well suited for symlinks (gitbash+zsh+windows).
./bin/rails javascript:install:bun installation goes fine.
the_best git:(master) ✗ bin/dev
20:07:23 web.1  | started with pid 4824
20:07:23 js.1   | started with pid 13740
20:07:23 css.1  | started with pid 16112
20:07:23 js.1   | unknown command: bun run build --watch
20:07:23 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.22
20:07:23 css.1  | yarn run v1.22.22
20:07:23 js.1   | $ bun bun.config.js --watch
20:07:24 css.1  | error Command "build:css" not found.
20:07:24 css.1  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
20:07:24 js.1   | 'bun' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
20:07:24 js.1   | operable program or batch file.
20:07:24 js.1   | error Command failed with exit code 1.
20:07:24 js.1   | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
20:07:24 js.1   | exited with code 1 ```


If you are using Bun, then you must have the Bun runtime already installed on your system. https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/tree/v1.3.1#installation

Ahhh separate install for that one. Got it, good to proceed with bun then, thank you! welcome to post as an answer to the question.
